# How to avoid the line overlapping on node and reroute the line in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am adding the circles dynamically and maintaining the connection between the circle like this

```
let drawLine = d3.svg.line().x(d => d[0]).y(d => d[1]);

let path = svg.append('path').
  attr('stroke', 'red').
  attr('stroke-width', 5).
  attr('fill', 'none').
  attr('d', drawLine([[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]));
```

As i am adding nodes dynamically, if there is any connection overlapped on the node then i want to reroute that line in a different path(Any path that should not overlap on any of the node) [Static example](https://jsfiddle.net/n1qyfbwv/)

In the above example there are 3 circles and there is connection between 2 big circles. The connected path is overlapped on the one small circle in the middle. so i want to maintain the same connection between those 2 circles but it shouldn't overlap on the nodes. I am new to d3 and i am not sure like d3.svg.line() is correct way to maintain the non overlapping connection between the nodes. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quadtatic Bezier curve instead:

```js
let svg = d3.select('#panel')
svg.append('circle')
   .attr('r', 40)
   .attr("cx", 50)
   .attr("cy", 50);
      
   svg.append('circle')
   .attr('r', 40)
   .attr("cx", 350)
   .attr("cy", 50);
   
   svg.append('circle')
   .attr('r', 20)
   .attr("cx", 200)
   .attr("cy", 50);
   
   let lineGenerator = d3.svg.line().x(d => d[0]).y(d => d[1]);
   
   const quadraticBezierLineGenerator = d => 
    `M ${d[0][0]},${d[0][1]} Q ${(d[0][0] + d[1][0])/2}, ${d[0][1] - 60} ${d[1][0]},${d[1][1]}`;
   
   
   let path = svg.append('path').
      attr('stroke', 'red').
      attr('stroke-width', 5).
      attr('fill', 'none').
      attr('d', quadraticBezierLineGenerator([[92, 50], [309, 50]]));
```

```css
    svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    svg circle {
      fill: white;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 3;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="panel"></svg>
```